# asp.net KendoUI AutoComplete HeaderTemplate Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have created new project in VisualStudio using KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC project template and I am getting this error while trying to use AutoComplete

'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.AutoCompleteBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderTemplate' and no extension method 'HeaderTemplate' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.AutoCompleteBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using code in [Link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/template.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have reference to Kendo.Mvc.UI dll ?  If you dont have try adding referencing from program files folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2013\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc3

"Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2013" will be different depending on kendo mvc wrapper version you have installed.

Comment: I only see one dll 'Kendo.Mvc.dll' in Binaries folder. No Kendo.MVC.UI.dll

Comment: Never mind. I just need .Template I guess. not sure why Telerik sample shows .HeaderTemplate